# why does pyrogram sign_in() causes asyncio error?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, pyrogram

first, I am creating Client object and connecting it

```
active_sessions[alice_user_id] = {'client': Client(alice_user_id, API_ID, API_HASH, workdir='sessions_tg')}
await active_sessions[alice_user_id]['client'].connect()
```

after it, I am sending code

```
sent_code_info = await active_sessions[alice_user_id]['client'].send_code(phone_number)
active_sessions[alice_user_id]['phone_number'] = phone_number
active_sessions[alice_user_id]['sent_code_info'] = sent_code_info
active_sessions[alice_user_id]['password'] = password
```

after getting the code from user I am trying to use sign_in()

```
phone_number = active_sessions[alice_user_id]['phone_number']
sent_code_info = active_sessions[alice_user_id]['sent_code_info']
password = active_sessions[alice_user_id]['password']
try:
    conf = await active_sessions[alice_user_id]['client'].sign_in(phone_number,         sent_code_info.phone_code_hash,phone_code)

except SessionPasswordNeeded:
    if password:
        try:
            await active_sessions[alice_user_id]['client'].check_password(password)
        except BadRequest:
            return BAD_LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD
    else:
        return BAD_LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD
```

when I am using sign_in() asyncio raise RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
how can I avoid this error? (I am using python 3.9)

if I delete this error from asyncio code small example work perfectly, but I cant use this in my project cause it raise other errors